# MySQL connect database fatal error

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

when my PHP page connect to mysql database, i get the following error;

[image: error screenshot]

I have installed MySQL 5.7.11. My PHP version is 7.0.2 installed with XAMPP. I have separately installed MySQL with MySQL Workbench.

I tried numerous solution in stackoverflow also. None of them worked;
I checked the following phpinfo page to confirm "Loaded Configuration File"

[image: PHP info page]

Your all help is appreciated. Thanks!!!!

UPDATE !!!

After your solution, it connects to database. But I get this new error;

[image: new error]

Comment: in PHP 7, mysql_* is closed, u need to use mysqli_* or PDO

Comment: Shouldn't be using mysql in the first place, as it's deprecated.

Comment: Thanks brothers all ! Now it says that I am connected to the database. But I get a new error. In my post I have uploaded the screenshot of it

Comment: You have to update all your queries to PDO or MySQLi, not just the connect.

Comment: Oh my god ! I wrote this website years ago. I am not familiar with MySQLi. I have to google now. Does changing take long time?

Answer (score 4):

`mysql` is not included in PHP 7+. You'll need to use the [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO_MYSQL`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) api.

The [php.net/mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) states:

> This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP
>   7.0.0. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

You should also consider, if you haven't already, replacing MySQL v5.7 with [MariaDB](http://mariadb.com) v10 (they use the same MySQLi/PDO_MySQL api).

Comment: Thanks brothers all ! Now it says that I am connected to the database. But I get a new error. In my post I have uploaded the screenshot of it

Comment: Same problem, you are using `mysql_` functions which are not included in PHP7+. You'll need to use `mysqli_` or `PDO` objects; you cannot use any function that starts `mysql_`.